# Second level of drop-down menu will not appear on hover

Tags: html, css

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s5G6N/3/)

I have a multi-level drop-down menu that has all its secondary (and higher) levels' heights set to zero, with `overflow:hidden`, as you can see here:

```css
/*second level*/
#navbar li ul{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;    
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
}
/*third level*/
#navbar li ul li ul{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 102%;
    top:0;
    height:0px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
}
```

On both of these elements' designated hovers, i have their heights set to 250px.As you can see here:

```css
#navbar li:hover > ul{
    height: 250px; 
}

#navbar li ul li:hover > ul{
    height: 250px; 
}
```

The second level appears just fine. The third level however does not appear at all. Does anyone know why?

update: the third level `li` elements don't seem to be picking up anything bad from the parent elements, at least from what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your css

```
#navbar li ul{
    width:286px;
}
#navbar li ul li ul{
    display:none;
}
#navbar li ul li:hover   ul{
    display:block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abdulmalik/Ykj2C/)

Comment: Oh I see it, instead of altering the height, you're simply having it toggle between `display:none` and `display:block`, am i right? is it possible to keep the height change so I can use the css3 transition?

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. You should use either opacity or absolute positioning to handle it.

```
#navbar ul li ul {
position:absolute;
left: -99999px;
}

#navbar ul li:hover > ul {
left: 0px;
}
```

OR
    #navbar ul li ul {
    opacity: 0;
    }

```
#navbar ul li:hover > ul{
opacity: 1;
}
```